# Как сделать, чтобы метод возвращал переменное количество результатов python

Tags: python, функции

Есть функция

```
def summa_and_raznost(a, b):
    summa = a + b
    raznost = b - a
    return summa, raznost
```

Можно ли вызвать функцию так, чтобы получать не все значения, а столько, сколько нужно, не создавая кортеж со скобками, множество или список, который надо бы было распарсить?
Например

```
summa, raznost = summa_and_raznost(2, 3)  # return 5, 1
```

и

```
summa = summa_and_raznost(2, 3)  # return 5
```

Если так нельзя, то как сделать по другому?

Comment: `my_sum, _ = sum_and_dif(2, 3)` PS никогда не используйте имена встроенных функций, типов или зарезервированные слова в качестве имен переменных - `sum()` - встроенная функция

Comment: для справки - имя функции `sum_and_dif` не "пересекается" со встроенными , поэтому его можно смело использовать...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В качестве примера можно взять функцию [divmod(a,b)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod), возвращающую кортеж, состоящий из результата целочисленного деления `a // b` и остатка от деления `a % b`:

```
res, mod = divmod(17,3)
print(res, mod)
>>> 5 2
```

существует [соглашение об использовании одиночного или двойного подчеркивания в качестве имени "ненужной" переменной (которой мы не собираемся пользоваться)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python):

```
res, __ = divmod(17, 3)
print(res)
>>> 5
```

переменная `__` при этом тоже доступна:

```
print(__)
>>> 2
```

---

также можно выбрать нужный элемент кортежа ([как подсказал в комментариях @Alex Titov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/860758/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-python/860779#comment1389138_860779)) - при этом память должна освободиться быстрее:

```
res = divmod(17, 3)[0]
print(res)
>>> 5
```

Comment: а чтобы она совсем не передавалась нельзя?

Comment: @Elefanobi, за передачу отвечает функция, а она не в курсе в каком контексте вы её вызываете. Можете создать другую функцию.

Comment: Кстати, "философский" вопрос :) , что лучше для 2-х параметров - `res, _ = divmod(17,3)`, или `res=divmod(17,3)[0]` ?

Comment: @AlexTitov, хороший вопрос! Наверное ваш вариант лучше, т.к. память не засоряется...

Comment: Вопрос действительно филосовский этот `[0]` слишком угнетающий) Как насчёт `divmod(17, 3)[False]`?

Comment: @vp_arth, если честно, меня вариант с `[False]` угнетает гораздо сильнее - приходиться думать что же этим хотел сказать автор...